# React JS table body component is not Updaing

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-component

**I have these two simplified React components,** 
Parent component :- `SecondaryLeader` 
 Child component :- `SecondaryLeaderDialog`

In parent Component I'm loading the table and in child component i'm using to the insert form. when I inert the form table is not fetching the data. when i refresh the page only it's fetching.


without refreshing I want to load the table 

Data is storing into  the database but not updating the table.

I would appreciate the help in figuring out why table is not updaing, as expected, and how to fix the code so that it is.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

**Parent component**

```
import React from 'react';
class SecondaryLeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {

      super(props);

      this.state={
        fixedHeader: true,
        secondaryleader_details:'',
user_type: localStorage.getItem('type'),
api_token: localStorage.getItem('user_token'),

    };

}

//This will update the states when component will receive new props
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    let SecondaryLeader = props.SecondaryLeader;

    this.setState({
        secondaryleader_details:props.secondaryleader_details == null ? '' :props.secondaryleader_details,
    });


}

render() {
const secondaryleader_details_list =this.state.secondaryleader_details;
return (
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Role</th>
</tr>
<tbody>

secondaryleader_details_list.map((item, index) => (
<tr>
<td>{item.secondaryleader} </td>
<td>{item.role_name} </td>
</tr>
)) 

</tboady>
</thead>
</table>
 );
}
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class SecondaryLeaderDialog extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            secondaryleader: '',
             role_name: '',

             api_token:localStorage.getItem('user_token'),

        };

        //This binds the context with the functions
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

    handleSubmit(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        const form_information = {
            secondaryleader_details: {

                secondaryleader: this.state.secondaryleader,
                role_name: this.state.role_name,



            },
            api_token: this.state.api_token,
            id: this.props.id,
        };
        self = this;
        {/**
         *This will call the add API of the form details
         */
        }

        APIS.add(form_information, 'conduct-session')
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.statusCode == '0') {
                    self.setState({errors: response.message});
                }else{

  alert('Your Details Added successfully');

                }

            });
            }

             render() {
             return(
             <div
              <form  id="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <label className="formset-label">Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="secondaryleader" id="secondaryleader" value={this.state.secondaryleader} onChange={this.handleChange}>
             <label className="formset-label">Role</label>
             <input type="text" name="role_name" id="role_name" value={this.state.role_name} onChange={this.handleChange}>
<RaisedButton label="Save"  primary onTouchTap={this.handleSubmit}/>
             </form>
             </div>
             );
             }
             }
```

Comment: Indentation is really helpful when adding big pieces of code, any chance you could improve the formatting of your question?

Comment: hi @Icepickle, this is what I exactly I want ,in my second component when I insert the form data is not fetching  in the table.when I refresh the page only it's  fetching

Comment: It might be just me, but I don't see where you are fetching the data in the first place, only where you handle the changes? Could it be part of your code is still missing? Also, I cannot believe this indentation is what you want, there seems to be no structure what so ever in your indentation

Comment: How SecondaryLeader is connected to child component SecondaryLeaderDialog. i cannot see you rendering SecondaryLeaderDialog in the parent

Comment: @Icepickle I'm new to react js <br/> In initial stage i'm calling API in index.js page and passing the properties to SecondaryLeader page
and Receiveing the propperty through componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: @Icepickle this is how I call the Api in index page APIS.get(this.state.api_token, 'get-SecondaryLeaderlist')
                     .then(function (response) {
                                 self.setState({
                                     secondaryleader_details: response.data,
  });
                                       
                               })
how can i call the api after insert data

Comment: @stack26 Sorry i missed that line <div className={'ap-btn-box '}> <SecondaryLeaderDialog assessment_id={id} role_name={role_name}/></div> this is how i connect

Comment: You should really look into state management libraries like redux or similar things, where you could create a store and react then gets rendered through a `Provider` component, that will update your components when there store (props) change. Currently, for me the question doesn't have enough information to give a meaningful answer for you

Comment: Please update your question with right snippet